# rust shm_open() function failed

Tags: rust, ipc, libc

this code:

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{O_CREAT, O_RDWR, shm_open};

use std::ffi::CString;

fn shm_create() {
    let name = CString::new("/shaman").unwrap().as_ptr();
    let fd = unsafe { shm_open(name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0o600 ) };
    println!("shm_open: {}", fd);
}

fn main() {
    shm_create();
}
```

always print:

```
shm_open: -1
```

the same c implementation works.

I am a rust newbie and the problem seems to be there.

I'm out of ideas... any suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code involves a dangling pointer:

```
let name = CString::new("/shaman").unwrap().as_ptr();
```

The string is gone by the time `shm_open` is called.  Try this instead:

```
let name = CString::new("/shaman").unwrap();
let fd = unsafe { shm_open(name.as_ptr(), O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0o600 ) };
```

Comment: Wonderfull, it works. Going to try to understand what is behind the dandling pointer. Many thanks.